# Image fader with rectangular fade-in expanding from middle to edges

Tags: jquery, easing, jquery-easing, image-masking

I'm replacing a custom Flash animation with a jQuery.  The old animation used a mask that moved like a curtain opening:  the center appears first and the image fades in laterally on both sides in a smooth expansion of the centered rectangular mask outwards to the edges.

Is there already way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

There are prebuilt options out there, like for instance [this example](http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/animate-curtains-opening-with-jquery/) on build internet.  Most likely you will have to take an example like this and customize it to fit your needs, but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply and link.  Their solution involved using opaque images as overlays and moving them.  What I am looking for is more an animated alpha mask.